# Disable PVP in minecraft 1.8.7 Windows

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I want to know how to disable pvp in minecraft 1.8.7. While playing with my brother we often hit each other so I was thinking how to turn pvp off on lan. Please try to avoid servers. 
Thank you

Comment: There is no 1.8.7 version of Mcpe. Are you talking about the win 10 metro app or the desktop app?  They are very very different.

Comment: I know that disabling pvp in minecraft pe is impossible until in a server, but now i want to know how to disable pvp in minecraft Windows edition

Comment: So, the win10 pe edition or desktop?  Pe version I believe is 0.12 desktop is 1.8.8 but atm I don't believe they include commands I the pe version (for win10)

Comment: What version of MC are you playing on? MCPE, Win 10, or PC v1.8.7?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to play Minecraft PE is in a server (not a local Wi-Fi server, an external server). When people make external servers, they can set different commands and stuff like that, therefore allowing them to disable **or** enable PVP.

Answer (score 0):

1: `/scoreboard teams add [teamname]`
2: `/scoreboard teams join [teamname] [player]`
3: `/scoreboard teams option [teamname] friendlyfire false`
For step 2: Do that for you and your brother.
Step one: Just use the name Minecraft